# Make post REST API calls using Angular2

Tags: rest, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, http-post

I am new to Angular2 and I'm trying to use the Ionic2 framework to build a mobile hybrid app.

I need to make a POST call to a REST based API and I'm unable to do so.

Can anyone suggest me in the direction to get the same done

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample for post request which is same in both in Angular 2 and Ionic 2. read more docs also.

```
 registerUser(registration: RegistrationTO): Promise<String> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let body = JSON.stringify(
      {
        "userName": registration.userId,
        "emailId": registration.emailId,
        "userId": registration.userId,
        "facultyCode": registration.facultyCode
      }
    );
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let params:URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    let requestOption: RequestOptionsArgs =
      {search: params,  headers: headers };
    return this.http
      .post(RegistrationUrl, body, requestOption)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().userTO.msg)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

call the function like this

```
this.loginService.registerUser(this.registration).then((msg)=>{console.log(msg)});
```